# Corresponding built-in types for Python

Tags: interoperability, external-calls, python

Where can I find the correspondence of built-in types between Mathematica and Python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can find what you're looking for [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/PythonExpression.html#569806988):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Tried to search within `External`-related functions but missed this one!